# RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in cmp: K means clustering

Tags: python, recursion, k-means

I am implementing the K means clustering algorithm. So far this is what I have:

```
import copy
import csv
import math
import random
import sys


class Centroid():
    def __init__(self, coordinates, _id):
      self.id = _id
      self.coordinates = coordinates
      self.elements = []

    def __repr__(self):
       return 'Centroid: ' + str(self.id)

    @property
    def count(self):
       return len(self.elements)



    def recalculate_coordinates(self):
       x = [sum(y)/len(y) for y in zip(*self.elements)]
       self.coordinates = x

    def reset_elements(self):
       self.previous_elements = []
       for el in self.elements:
          self.previous_elements.append(el)
       self.elements = []

class Kmeans():
  def __init__(self):
     self.k = int(sys.argv[2])
     self.prepare_data()
     self.iterations = 0

  def prepare_data(self):
     filename = sys.argv[1]
     self.dataset = []
     with open(filename, 'rb') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
        for row in reader:
            tuplified = tuple(map(float, row))
            self.dataset.append(tuplified)
     self.create_centroids()

  def create_centroids(self):
    self.centroids = []
    for i in xrange(self.k):
        chosen = random.choice(self.dataset)
        cent = Centroid(chosen, i+1)
        self.centroids.append(cent)

def main():
  k = Kmeans()
  def iterate(k):
    k.iterations += 1
    for item in k.dataset:
        candidates = []
        for centroid in k.centroids:
            z = zip(item, centroid.coordinates)
            squares = map(lambda x: (x[0]-x[1])**2, z)  
            added = sum(squares)
            edistance = math.sqrt(added)
            candidates.append((centroid, edistance))
        winner = min(candidates, key=lambda x: x[1])
        winner[0].add_element(item)
    for centroid in k.centroids:
        centroid.reset_elements()
        centroid.recalculate_coordinates()

    status_list = []
    for centroid in k.centroids:
        boole = sorted(centroid.elements) == sorted(centroid.previous_elements)
        status_list.append(boole)

    if False in status_list:
        iterate(k)
    print k.centroids
    print k.iterations
  iterate(k)


if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

However, I keep getting an error `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in cmp`. I have tried several refactors with no success. Can anyone please tell me what might be the problem. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Some indentation is wrong, and there's some relevant code missing. I don't see anything recursive in what you show us.

Comment: It is in `def iterate` the third last line.

Comment: On what line does the exception occur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the error is on this line:

```
boole = sorted(centroid.elements) == sorted(centroid.previous_elements)
```

what's most likely occurring is that you have circular references within `centroids.elements` and `centroids.previous_elements`, so the comparison operations (performed in both the `sorted` call and the `==`) continues to traverse each list cyclically.

A simple demonstration of this behavior (in Python 3):

```
>>> x = []
>>> y = [x]
>>> x.append(y)
>>> x == y
Traceback (most recent call last)
  ....
   x == y    
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

Comment: Thanks that was the issue. Can't upvote it though cause of reps